# Linux Audio record and quality comparison

Tags: linux, performance, testing, audio, ffmpeg

I am starting a project to test the audio performance on linux.

What I need to do is to play the audio on our websystem and check the audio quality (or just check it has audio output) on linux.

1. I am going to record the audio on linux with ffmpeg. Is there any other better choice?
2. I don't know how to (automation) check I recorded is what I played, as well as the quality of recorded audio.

Comment: Have you found a solution to compare audio qualities?

Comment: There is a manual compare tools on windows but I didn't found a good solution for automation cross platform....

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is PESQ (Perceptual Evaluation of Sound Quality). However I have not found anything which is open source/free and out of the box.

You can download the recommendation from here:
http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-P.862-200511-I!Amd2/en
Basically this is the reference implementation of PESQ.

Sevana has an audio quality analyser which is not an ITU standard, it is AQuA:
http://www.sevana.fi/aqua_wiki.php
It is available for linux but I think you have to pay for it.

You can also check the similarities for two audio files with cross-correlation, please refer to here:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar

I just learned that lot of people are using Matlab or Octave to generate the necessary data, for example:
http://bagustris.blogspot.ie/2011/11/calculate-time-lag-from-cross.html